# javafx make new label on another fxml on button clicked

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I want to create new label in another fxml when a button is clicked. I used the following code but the following exception is thrown

> java.lang.RuntimeException: 
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

The code:

**`Controller.java`**

```
public class Controller {
   public AnchorPane anchorPane;
    public void OpenSecond() throws Exception{
        Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample1.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void AddLabe(){
        Label label = new Label("Label");
        anchorPane.getChildren().add(label);
    }
}
```

**`second.java`**

```
public class Second {
    public void AddLiabel()
    {
        Controller controller = new Controller();
        controller.AddLabe();
    }
}
```

I am using IntelliJ IDEA and Scene builder

Comment: You never initialize the `anchorPane` field for the controller you create using `Controller controller = new Controller();` there should be a *"Caused by NullPointerException"* somewhre in your stacktrace...

Comment: thanks for Answering ......... how can i initialize the anchorPane?

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting this exception because Java couldn't find the specified file or it is empty. Search for

```
    Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException:
```

in the exception.

Adding the "sample1.fxml" and initializing it with a pane should fix the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>


<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="275.0" prefWidth="300.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" />
```

Comment: I had Initiate the anchorPane by giving Id to it in the Scene Builder.

Comment: The controller class is the controller of the sample1.fxml? Is the sample1.fxml in the same directory as the controller class?

Comment: controller class is the controller of the sample.fxml and Second class is the controller of the sample1.fxml

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you miss annotation for anchorPane and JavaFX didn't initialize it. Try next:

```
 @FXML
 public AnchorPane anchorPane;
```

and make sure `anchorPane` is listed in your FXML file.